# How to get a substring from a formatted string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get a substring **403162** from the given string **Praveen(403162)** in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @searchString NVARCHAR(20) = 'Praveen(403162)'
DECLARE @startFrom INT= CHARINDEX('(',@searchstring) + 1
DECLARE @length INT = CHARINDEX(')',@searchstring) - @startFrom
SELECT SUBSTRING(@searchstring,@startFrom, @length) AS RESULT
```

If you want to do this in one line:

```
DECLARE @searchString NVARCHAR(20) = 'Praveen(403162)'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@searchstring,
       CHARINDEX('(',@searchstring) + 1, 
       CHARINDEX(')',@searchstring) - CHARINDEX('(',@searchstring) - 1) AS RESULT
```

Comment: Wah..!! that is working like a charm.!! Thank you So much Tanner .!!

Comment: +1 is giving extra character - 1 will give exact output small correction that's it.

Comment: Tanner, but the second inline option is not working. :(

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name, CHARINDEX('(', column_name)+1, CHARINDEX(')', column_name)-CHARINDEX('(', column_name)-1) from table_name
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f0cb/3)

Comment: what is dual? even without 'dual', the query not returns the result

Comment: `dual` is an Oracle "feature" for when you don't really use a table. In SqlServer you can just leave out the `from <table>` part, in Oracle you can't.

Comment: @PraveenVR replace column_name by your the column name, and table with the table_name. Check the sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Name VARCHAR(100)

Select @Name = 'Praveen(403162)'

Select @Name = SUBSTRING(@name,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Name),LEN(@Name))
Select SUBSTRING (@Name,1,6)
```