# how to split values in column in SQL based on string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a table name test(id,params)
Which has values (1,$ch=20$ph=9875567$ng=hutdj)

i want to take only Ph value , that means output should be 9875567

Comment: I must know why are you storing your data this way?

Comment: You want someone to do this for you? or you wanna try something and let us know where you have issues?

Comment: Probably best done on the client side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a substring '403162' from the given string 'Praveen(403162)' in sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529309/how-to-get-a-substring-403162-from-the-given-string-praveen403162-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @searchString NVARCHAR(50) = '$ch=20$ph=9875567$ng=hutdj'
DECLARE @startFrom INT= CHARINDEX('ph=',@searchstring) + 3
DECLARE @length INT = CHARINDEX('$ng',@searchstring) - @startFrom
SELECT SUBSTRING(@searchstring,@startFrom, @length) AS RESULT
```

Demo **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31892)**

The inline version:

```
DECLARE @searchString NVARCHAR(50) = '$ch=20$ph=9875567$ng=hutdj'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@searchstring,
   CHARINDEX('ph=',@searchstring) + 3, 
   CHARINDEX('$ng',@searchstring) - CHARINDEX('ph=',@searchstring) - 3) AS RESULT
```

Demo **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31896)**

Answer (score 0):

Using XML

```
select *, params_xml.value('(/x[@n="ph"]/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
from (
    select *, cast(stuff(replace(replace(params,'=', '">'), '$', '</x><x n="'), 1, 4, '') + '</x>' as xml) as params_xml
    from test
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
The first substring will return all characters after $ph= and the second substring will return all characters from the resulted string to the next $

```
SET @params = SUBSTRING(
                SUBSTRING(@s, PATINDEX('%$ph%',@s) + 4 , 
                          LEN(@S)- PATINDEX('%$ph%',@s)-3),
                0,
                PATINDEX('%$%', SUBSTRING(@s, PATINDEX('%$ph%',@s) + 4 ,
                         LEN(@S)- PATINDEX('%$ph%',@s)-3)))
```