# Find a string between two string values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Probably a simple one but I'm having trouble getting this to work in SQL. ( easy with VBA ).

Given xxx_123_abcd I need to extract the 123 part. whatever code searchs for the _ should always work from the left because sometimes and string might be xxx_123_abcd_xxx.

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: This is not very well explained.  Can you elaborate on exactly what you need?

Comment: My advice is: Avoid strings like 'xxx_123_abcd_xxx' in an rdbms, if you are interested in the substrings. Have four columns instead: 'xxx', '123', 'abcd', 'xxx'. As to string manipulation: What do you want to extract? The first integer? The second substring?

Comment: The number is always 123? The Length is always 3 digits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a substring '403162' from the given string 'Praveen(403162)' in sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529309/how-to-get-a-substring-403162-from-the-given-string-praveen403162-in-sql)

Comment: will the 123 part always be 3 digits?

Comment: One again sorry for the bad explanation. The stright may not always be three digits, but will always be enclosed by two _. This is the reason i have selected the below as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CHARINDEX to search for the underscores, to be able to extract the part of the string you need with SUBSTRING. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('_', MyColumn)+1,
        CHARINDEX('_', MyColumn, CHARINDEX('_', MyColumn)+1)-CHARINDEX('_', MyColumn)-1)
FROM
    MyTable
```

MyColumn = `xxx_123_abcd_xxx` produces `123` using the above code.

Assumptions: The string you are looking for is enclosed by the first and second occurence of an underscore.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To all, i should have specified that the return value i was looking for could be two didgits

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom Split function such as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/34a00a62-2027-4cad-b515-a41dc71765e3/split-a-string-using-sql).

If the xxx_123 part is always the same length, you could also use

```
SUBSTRING('xxx_123_abcd',5,7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions

1. The numeric string you are searching for is always three digits
2. It is always preceded by an '_'
3. It immediately follows the first occurrence of '_' in the string

Then this will work

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('xxx_123_abcd',CHARINDEX('_','xxx_123_abcd')+1,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also go with this

```
SELECT LEFT(Col1,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Col1+'a')-1) from(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Col1), LEN(Col1)) As Result From table
)x
```